Convert 0 to 255 to single Char
I am trying to convert values from 0 to 255 to a single char.
I am using chr. But this is somehow converting a number like 255 to a two char string.
I add up those values to a string which is then converted with bytes(string , 'UTF-8') into a bytestream and written over serial to UART.


#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import serial

def asbyte(v):
    return chr(v & 0xFF)
def printStdErr(*objs):
#    print("", *objs, file=stderr)
    print("")
class LightYModem:
    soh = 1     # 128 byte blocks
    stx = 2     # 1K blocks
    eot = 4
    ack = 6
    nak = 0x15
    ca =  0x18          # 24
    crc16 = 0x43        # 67
    abort1 = 0x41       # 65
    abort2 = 0x61       # 97

    packet_len = 1024
    expected_packet_len = packet_len+5
    packet_mark = stx

    def __init__(self):
        self.seq = None
        self.ymodem = None

    def blocking_read(self):
        ch = ''
        while not ch:
            ch = self.ymodem.read(1)
        printStdErr("read %d " % ord(ch))
        return ch

    def write(self, packet):
            #print(packet)
            b = bytes(packet, 'UTF-8')
            print(b)

            self.ymodem.write(b)

            return len(packet);

    def flush(self):
        pass
        #self.ymodem.flush()

    def _read_response(self):
        ch1 = self.blocking_read()
        ch1 = ord(ch1)
        printStdErr("response %d" % (ch1))

        if ch1==LightYModem.ack and self.seq==0:    # may send also a crc16
            ch2 = self.blocking_read()
        elif ch1==LightYModem.ca:                   # cancel, always sent in pairs
            ch2 = self.blocking_read()
        return ch1

    def transfer(self, file, ymodem, output):
        self.ymodem = ymodem
        """
        file: the file to transfer via ymodem
        ymodem: the ymodem endpoint (a file-like object supporting write)
        output: a stream for output messages
        """

        file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        size = file.tell()
        file.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        response = self.send_filename_header("binary", size)
        while response==LightYModem.ack:
            response = self.send_packet(file, output)

        file.close()
        if response==LightYModem.eot:
            self._send_close()

        return response
    def _send_ymodem_packet(self, data):
        # pad string to 1024 chars
        data = data.ljust(LightYModem.packet_len)
        seqchr = asbyte(self.seq & 0xFF)
        print("seqchr : "+str(len(seqchr)))
        seqchr_neg = asbyte((255-self.seq) & 0xFF)
        print("seqchr_neg : "+str(len(seqchr_neg)))
        crc16 = '\x00\x00'
        print("bytes "+ str(bytes([255])))
        packet = asbyte(LightYModem.packet_mark) + seqchr + seqchr_neg + data + crc16
        if len(packet)!=LightYModem.expected_packet_len:
            raise Exception("packet length is wrong!")
        self.packet = packet
        written = self.write(packet)
        printStdErr("sent packet data, flush..."+str(written))
        self.flush()
        printStdErr("wait response..")
        response = self._read_response()
        if response==LightYModem.ack:
            ("sent packet nr %d " % (self.seq))
            self.seq += 1
        return response
    def send_packet(self, file, output):
        response = LightYModem.eot
        data = file.read(LightYModem.packet_len)
        if len(data):
            response = self._send_ymodem_packet(data)
        return response
    

    def send_filename_header(self, name, size):
        self.seq = 0
        packet = name 
        packet += asbyte(0) 
        packet += str(size) 
        packet += ' '
        return self._send_ymodem_packet(packet)

    def transfer(self, file, ymodem, output):
        self.ymodem = ymodem
        """
        file: the file to transfer via ymodem
        ymodem: the ymodem endpoint (a file-like object supporting write)
        output: a stream for output messages
        """

        file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        size = file.tell()
        file.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        response = self.send_filename_header("binary", size)
        while response==LightYModem.ack:
            response = self.send_packet(file, output)

        file.close()
        if response==LightYModem.eot:
            self._send_close()

        return response
def ymodem(args):
    ser = serial.Serial('COM24', 115200, serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
    os.chdir(r'D:\projects\testprojects\code\Test1\config')
    file = open(os.getcwd()+'\testfile.bin', 'rb')
    result = LightYModem().transfer(file, ser, sys.stderr)
    file.close()
    print("result: " + str(result))

    try:
        while (True):
            print(ser.read())
    except:
        pass
    print("Done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ymodem(sys.argv)


Tryed to build the bytes - Array for the different elements and added the 0-255 as uint8. Then I cannot see anything on the STM32 I use as a recepient over UART.
UPDATE:
When I use bytes with LATIN-1 I get the 0 to 255 in a single byte transferred. If i try to send a single element from a LATIN-1 encoded bytearray, it doesnt work.Why is that so?
        seqchr ='\x00'
        seqchr_neg = '\xFF'
        packet =  seqchr + seqchr_neg 


...


    def write(self, packet):
        bh = bytearray(packet, 'LATIN-1')
        ch = bytes(packet[0], 'LATIN-1')
        print(ch)
        print(bh[0])
        self.ymodem.write(bh )#receive only zero on my STM
        self.ymodem.write(ch)# receive the 0x02 on my STM



chr returns a str value. That value can be encoded to a one- or two-byte bytes value depending on what encoding is used.

You don't want to use chr to get a string that might have a two-byte UTF-8 encoding; you just want the literal bytes value for a single 8-bit integer.
>>> bytes([230])
b'\xe6'

or
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('B', 230)
b'\xe6'


bytes endoded in LATIN-1 works for me, when sending it and receiving it via uart with my stm32. bytearray encoded in LATIN-1 does not. Why is that so?

I'd have to see exactly what you are doing. For the most part, the only difference between bytes and bytearray is mutability. Both represent integer values between 0 and 255, inclusive.

I updated my question with the code excerpt
